# Using razor as rendering engine in Sitecore. With or without the rest of mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, sitecore

We just upgraded our Sitecore solution to Sitecore 7.0 and want to start to make a gradual shift away from xslt. At the same time we are considering how much of the mvc concepts, we would like to use in the solution. We would definitely like to introduce Razor. But probably not all of mvc at this point.

The sitecore mvc documentation states that:

> Both ASP.NET WebForms and MVC are supported and can be mixed, although a single request must 
>   be rendered by either WebForms or MVC.

(http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/66/sitecore_mvc_developer_guide-a4.pdf#search=%22mvc%22)

So I guess that we need to make a lot of changes to existing layouts and renderings, to be able to use Razor.

Right now it seems like the fastest way to start making new renderings in razor is to use the module [Razor for Sitecore](http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Razor_for_Sitecore.aspx).

According to the requirements of the module however it doesn't seem to be supported in Sitecore 7.0 (or 6.6). Is that because I am missing something?

To say it short: What is the best way to use Razor as rendering engine in an existing sitecore 7.0 solution that already contains a lot of xslt's, sublayouts, layouts, that I would not like to rewrite all at once. Can I use [Razor for Sitecore](http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Razor_for_Sitecore.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

As you noted, Razor for Sitecore is not supported in Sitecore 7, so I would not recommend that.

Moving from a web forms to an mvc project is never going to be simple, but you can do it bit by bit, rather than doing the whole project at once.

You would need to re-create your main layouts and common renderings using the mvc renderings first. These would be renderings that appear on every page. Headers, footers, user control, navigation etc...

Once you have done that, you can then start to move the site over a page/module at a time. So pick the home page and re-write all the renderings on there to use mvc, then pick another page etc...

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it myself, but this may be of interest:

https://github.com/kamsar/Blade